# Get test number in tests

Tags: perl, testing

My title may be a little bit poorly formed, but the main idea is: I'm running my tests via prove, and they start to run quite long (1min+, much DB initialisation involved etc). I wanna try making my tests run in parallel. I'd want all my tests to create a separate database, create tables in it, populate the tables and run my tests. I'm using MySQL and I've put the DB into RAM, so it might work. But for that, I'd need a unique ID in my test files, so each of them could create it's own DB.

Does prove support providing the test number for tests? First test would get the number 1, second 2, etc. So i could create mydb_test1, mydb_test2 etc.